# getting string from simplexmlobject without xpath

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I'm going crazy here... again!!

I have this simplexml file:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PubmedArticle] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [MedlineCitation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Owner] => NLM
                                    [Status] => In-Process
                                )

                            [PMID] => 20538400
                            [DateCreated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [Year] => 2010
                                    [Month] => 07
                                    [Day] => 08
                                )

                            [Article] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [PubModel] => Print-Electronic
                                        )
etc.....
```

I want to have the "DateCreated" in this particular way: 2010-07-08
**The following code works...:**

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//MedlineCitation') as $MedlineCitation)
{

    foreach ($MedlineCitation->DateCreated as $date)
    {
             foreach ($date as $ymd)
             {
             $datecreated .= $ymd . "-"; 
             }
     $datecreated = substr($datecreated, 0, -1);
     echo $datecreated;
     $datecreated = "";
     }
}
```

output: 2010-07-08 
But... i want it without xpath, because i need to have another peace of code in this "foreach loop" that doesn't work with xpath...

This code doesn't doesn't work....:

```
foreach ($xml->PubmedArticle as $MedlineCitation)
{
       foreach ($MedlineCitation->DateCreated as $date)
       {
          foreach ($date as $ymd)
          {
          $datecreated .= $ymd . "-"; 
          }
        $datecreated = substr($datecreated, 0, -1);
        echo $datecreated;
        $datecreated = "";
        }
}
```

And this also doesn't wok...:

```
foreach ($xml->PubmedArticle as $MedlineCitation)
    {
    $datecreated = "";

    $datecreated = $MedlineCitation->DateCreated->Year;
    $datecreated = $datecreated . "-" . $MedlineCitation->DateCreated->Month;
    $datecreated = $datecreated . "-" . $MedlineCitation->DateCreated->Day;
    echo $datecreated;
    }
```

Best regards!
Thijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just getting a little confused over how the XML structure is accessed in SimpleXML.  To get your dates, you could loop over each `MedlineCitation` within each `PubmedArticle` like:

```
// Loop over each <PubmedArticle>
foreach ($xml->PubmedArticle as $article)
{
    // Loop over each <MedlineCitation> within this <PubmedArticle>
    foreach ($article->MedlineCitation as $citation) {
        // Get formatted created date
        $date_created = sprintf(
            "%04d-%02d-%02d",
            $citation->DateCreated->Year,
            $citation->DateCreated->Month,
            $citation->DateCreated->Day
        );
        echo $date_created . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

If there is only ever one `MedlineCitation` within a `PubmedArticle` then the inner loop is unnecessary and you could do:

```
// Loop over each <PubmedArticle>
foreach ($xml->PubmedArticle as $article)
{
    // Use the <MedlineCitation> within this <PubmedArticle>
    $citation = $article->MedlineCitation;
    // Get formatted created date
    $date_created = sprintf(
        "%04d-%02d-%02d",
        $citation->DateCreated->Year,
        $citation->DateCreated->Month,
        $citation->DateCreated->Day
    );
    echo $date_created . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: THANKS!! this is the solution! I missed one level in the structure!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have loaded xml file content into $xml then try this snippet

//

$yy = $xml->DateCreated->Year;
$mm = $xml->DateCreated->Month;
$dd = $xml->DateCreated->Day;

$datecreated = $yy.'-'.$mm.'-'.$dd; // yyyy-mm-dd

echo $datecreated;

// 
Hope this help!

Comment: It works when i use the whole path in the foreach loop... so it looks likes the $MedlineCitation doesn't fill...? in the: "foreach ($xml->PubmedArticle as $MedlineCitation)" loop...?